XKB, Capslock problem and Fn+multimedia keys remapping
trying to finish a XKB custom layout, all keys seems fine but :
1- Capslock doesn't work for non-alphadecimal keys
It works for 'a' that turns into 'A', but not for ',' that should turn into its 'Shifted' equivalent. Works with 'Shift' as expected though.
Tried this in '/etc/default/keyboard' :
XKBOPTIONS="caps:shift"

Ideally, I'm looking for the same behavior than CapsUnlock (https://www.brainsystems.com/capsunlock/) :
It turns CapsLock locking the same way a real typewriting machine do, ie you've to press Shift+CapsLock to actually lock it, otherwise it acts like Shift. Pressing CapsLock again unlocks it.
It prevents to accidentally pressing CapsLock and writing IN ALL CAPS FOR THE next few characters until you realize the mistake, unlock it, then having to Backspace several times and type again. I'm sure you've been there already too, admit it.
2- Multimedia keys are not remapped properly (https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols) on Function keys with Fn
I've tried every kind of combination without luck :
include "level3(ralt_switch)"

key <FK04> { [ F4, F4, F4, F4, F4, F4, XF86AudioMicMute ] }; // Nb of useful 'modifiers' not clear

Yet when I press Fn+F4 the Mic is not muted. There is another "shortcut" linked to that key that is executed instead. How to supersede the multimedia keys' configuration ?
I've tried 'evtest', 'xev', 'wev', 'showkey', 'xmodmap -pke' (to get feedback), ... without much luck.
From my readings so far, the keyboard layout customization is a very complex and touchy subject, involving several files around the kernel, each with their own particular syntax.
Documentation is partial, outdated or overly wordy without clear overview of the system architecture and what files to modify to get the expected behavior.
Regards.
